# '<' operator in terminal command line

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, terminal

Does `cat < test.txt` perform differently comparing to normal `cat test.txt`?

As I understood that

> < takes the standard input from the file on the right and inputs it
>   into the program on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `cat file.txt`, the system calls to open and read the file are made by `cat`, while in `cat < file.txt` those calls are made by the shell, which then pipes the file's contents to `cat` via standard input. The end result is the same, and as far as I know there are no other differences.

Comment: Clear explanation. Thank you ; )

Comment: Good answer. The only situation where I could see it making a difference is if `file.txt` can't be opened by the current shell (because  the current user doesn't have the required permissions) and `cat` is being run with super-user privileges by `sudo`.